# CSS Zoom and mouse coordinates in Plotly graphs

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly.js

Setting the CSS zoom property results in Plotly.js incorrectly translating the mouse coordinates. The problem could easily be solved if there was a way to override the existing coordinate getter in JavaScript, to return a scaled version of the coordinates based on the zoom.
Is there an easy way to do such an override?